# Laravel's eloquent relationships and MySQLs foreign keys - belongsTo not resulting in a relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-7

I think I'm having a misunderstanding of Laravel's eloquent relationships (version 7).

Main question is: Is a MySQL foreign-key required for them to work? And is an FK required both ways?

Situation: I have users, I have accounts. Each user has one account, each account belongs to one user.

Users migration:

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamp('updated_at');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
        });
    }
}
```

Accounts migration:

```
class CreateAccountsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('accounts', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->id('owner');
            $table->bigInteger('currency');
            $table->integer('currencyGenerators');
            $table->foreign('owner')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->timestamp('updated_at');
            $table->dateTime('lastResourceUpdate')->nullable()->useCurrent();
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
        });
    }
}
```

Thus I have a MySQL FK accounts.owner referencing users.id.

User Model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    ...
    
    public function account(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Account::class, 'owner');
    }
}
```

Account Model:

```
class Account extends Model
{
    ...

    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

I can retrieve the user's account:

```
$users = User::all();
dd($users[0]);

App\User {#1030 ▼
#primaryKey: "id"
...
#relations: array:1 [▼
"account" => App\Account {#1185 ▶}
]
...
```

But I cant get the account's user:

```
$accounts = Account::all();
dd($accounts[0]);

App\Account {#1241 ▼
    #primaryKey: "owner"
    ...
    #relations: array:1 [▼
    "user" => null
    ]
    ...
```

Do I need an FK in my users table referencing account's owner? (Because Laravel's documentation mentions `return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key');` on https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#introduction.

Or what is my issue here?

Comment: You have to use 'owner' column in Account model 
return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'owner','id');

Comment: @sohailansari that actually seems to do the trick oO Though I am uncertain how that makes sense. But I guess I'm having an issue understanding relations. Would you type an answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use 'owner' column in Account model

```
return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'owner','id');
```